# Hadoop-2.2.0 "It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. "

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop.After I have installed the hadoop-2.2.0 on single-node,I visited the url:localhost:9000,it returned the following result:

> It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.

I have configured my core-site.xml as below:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    <description>The name of the defaultfile system. Either the literal string "local" or a host:port.
    </description>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
```

How can I solved the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't "browse" to a hdfs address: that is used internally by hadoop.

Comment: May I ask one or two more question, what is the port of "Map/Reduce Administration" or where to configure it, what are the other ports number, I once used the port 9000.

Comment: I've only used cloudera:the web UI urls are here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/

Answer (score 22):

For a basic single node configuration here the web interfaces (`hadoop1` is my hostname):

- Resource Manager:               `http://hadoop1:8088`
- Web UI of the NameNode daemon:  `http://hadoop1:50070`
- HDFS NameNode web interface:    `http://hadoop1:8042`

Comment: I logged onto the `master` node and earlier I was trying with `127.0.0.1` which didn't work, using the hostname in the URL as pointed out by @carloreggiani it worked. cluster metrics usnig resource manager `curl -X GET http://$(hostname):8088/ws/v1/cluster/metrics` (if connection refused check if resource manager port is different)

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps:
http://hostname:50070/dfshealth.html
http://hostname:50075/datanode.html
http://hostname:8088/cluster
http://hostname:8042/node

Or simply: 
http://hostname:50070/
http://hostname:50075/
http://hostname:8088/
http://hostname:8042/

Answer (score 3):

There are other HTTP ports that would run in server for monitoring. Example: 50070, 8088, 9870, 9864, 9868, 16010, 16030

Hadoop IPC(Inter Process Communicator) ports (Eg. 9000) cannot be accessed through your web browser.

You can find the ports that can be accessed in browser by the following command:

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

For example, the ports in my server were:

Hadoop Cluster - http://server-name:8088/cluster

Hadoop NameNode/DFS Health - http://server-name:9870/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

Hadoop DataNode - http://server-name:9864/datanode.html

Hadoop Status - http://server-name:9868/status.html

HBase Master Status - http://server-name:16010/master-status

HBase Region server - http://server-name:16030/rs-status

Answer (score 2):

check this out, `http://localhost:50070`
It works fine on win10.
it's already discussed [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/29202/opening-a-hdfs-file-in-browser).

Answer (score 0):

cannot browse Hadoop Distributed File System with that IPC port number.
As I did before like

```
hdfs://localhost:8032
```

If you want to browse HDFS using web user interface use this instead.

```
http://anton:50070
```

Here anton is my hostname of the machine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPuMR.png)